# Unable to get wsdl from CXF service

Tags: jetty, cxf

I'm trying to get a CXF service running on existing jetty server (not stand-alone).
I see the list of services at http://localhost:9100/cxfservices
But, when I click on the wsdl link, I get 404 error. What am I missing here?

WSDL link is:http://localhost:9100/cxfservices/QueryService?wsdl

Endpoint address: http://localhost:9100/cxfservices/QueryService

web.xml

...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cxfservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

...

beans.xml

...

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="queryService"
    implementor="com.sap.odp.cxf.QueryServiceImpl"
    address="/QueryService"/>
```

...

Comment: Do you see any other messages in your error log - since you are able to see the list of services, it indicates that your CXFServlet and mappings are good, CXFServlet should have continued to handle the request for the WSDL also. Can you confirm that you are in a Spring environment, if so do you have the following in your Spring config files: <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>

Comment: can you invoke the service using a client, e.g. soapui? In case the service is packaged as a WAR file, did you try to deploy it to a different container (maybe on tomcat)?